# how do I apply watermark on multiple videos in the current directory with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

Linux + ffmpeg

I have a folder with 300 videos. I need to apply the same watermark on all these videos, so in the folder I have 300 video files + 1 png file which is my watermark, how do I do this without the system asking to overwrite the files? how to generate a different name for each output file? that is at least video1.mp4 video2.mp4 etc...

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' output.mp4
```

I found something like that.

It works without errors, but asks if I want to replace the previous video with the next video to be tagged:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' -strict -2 "$~nf-360p.mp4"; done
```

How do I generate a command that has the flag that in each mp4 file processed to apply the watermark of the current directory, gets a different name so that the output files were not overwritten?

Thanks.

Comment: You're mixing Windows and Bash script syntax here, not sure where you got that weird loop command from. `for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f"…; done`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [slhck's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852413/how-do-i-apply-watermark-on-multiple-videos-in-the-current-directory-with-ffmpeg/46873449#comment80673648_46852413), I found the solution:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' -strict -2 "$f-marked.mp4"; done
```